# Tooltip not working on all places

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, qtip

Ok,

I am searching for over 2 hours now what the problem is but i simply cannot find it.
I want to create a tooltip once you hover the "vacatures".

Here it works:
http://www.horecavacaturebank.nl/vacature-type/full-time/

And here it does not:
http://www.horecavacaturebank.nl/

What i did:
I duplicated the js part in theme-scripts.js to make a new selector that creates the tooltip.

Then in my PHP-file (which outputs both on the "fulltime"page and the homepage) i changed the title tag of the LI item.

I think it should be some "directory"-issue since "fulltime" is a deeper directory, but i cant be sure.

I hope that i explained myself right...
What am i doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess: selectors used to setup tooltips are not equal on the two pages. Anyway, I would suggest you to improve your question with a description on what you have done so far, what you have checked, etc.

Comment: @Dario Solera I also think there is something wrong with the selectors, but i cannot find it. I updated my post with a better description. Seen the -1.... I don't want to be one of those guys who asks incomplete questions :(

Answer (score 2):

Might be this line, that causes it to not work:

```
jQuery('.tag-input-commas').tag({separator: ','});
```

It generates this error on the page where the tooltip doesn't work:

> theme-scripts.js:18Uncaught TypeError:
>   Object # has no method 'tag'

You should fire up Firebug (in Firefox) or Developer Tools (in Chrome) and fix all the .js related errors, and by doing so, you will most likely solve it.

Comment: You still have errors. This line might be what's causing it now:  jQuery('textarea.grow').autogrow();
"theme-scripts.js:62Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'autogrow' (repeated 2 times)"

Answer (score 1):

on the "second" page the divs with the qtip-class are completely missing.

Comment: i also do not find them on the 1st page. Where did you find them? Can you state me which line?

Comment: sorry, i don't have a line. it is right after

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wibiya.com/Toolbars/dir_0835/Toolbar_835810/toolbar_835810_4decf5b8e719a.js"></script>

but it's on 'display:none' unless it is shown. i just see it with firebug